# change solution file to a different folder

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

How do I change the folder of my existing solution file (sln)?

It's right now inside one of my project's folder; if I cut the solution file and paste it in the root folder,it doesn't load any of my projects.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Relocate Visual Studio project (.sln) file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626631/how-to-relocate-visual-studio-project-sln-file)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The solution file is just a text file. You should be able to move it and then edit it to make sure that any relative paths referenced in the file are correct.

I've also been able to right-click on the solution file in the solution explorer and then use save-as to save it in a different location. That doesn't seem to work everytime for me though.

Comment: Edited my answer with a different method that seems to work - sometimes.

Comment: This worked for me - Opened the .sln with notepad and changed all the paths to my new one. Thanks !

Comment: Still relevant in 2018. I'd add as a second step that after opening the new solution: (1) drop all projects & solution items, (2) copy all the project folders  except for the solution file to the new location, (3) re-add all projects and references from the new location. Now all your solution & projects are in the same folder group. (If that's your intention.)

Answer (score 69):

Open solution explorer in Visual Studio and select the solution.
Click on **File > Save MyProject.sln As ...**
and choose the new location.

Comment: I can conform it works in VS2013.
If the sln is under source control first go to File | Source Control | Advanced | Change Source Control. Select the solution and click "Unbind". After saving the .sln to the new folder you can bind it again to source control.

Comment: ...afterwards remove the old .sln and .vssscc files from source control (in source control explorer) and from disk and add the new files to source control (if not done automatically).

Comment: Using VS2012 here, for my case I need to first click on the solution file in the solution explorer, then only I'm able to see File->Save MyProject.sln As... Hope this helps someone

Comment: This option is not there in Visual Studio 2017 (15.4.2) Enterprise with 30+ projects.  Unbinding from Source Control does not help.

Answer (score 11):

Open a blank solution, save it to a location where you would like to move. Then add "Existing Project" and select the Old.sln file to add all the projects under the old solution file.

Answer (score 5):

I just had to do this with some legacy projects I inherited so thought it might be worth documenting...

After upgrading from VS 2005 solution, I noticed that the solution file was at the same level as the project files. Our standard is to have the solution file one level above.

[image: Undesired location of solution file.]

Opening the solution file in 'Notepad' I see the following:

[image: Unchanged Solution file opened in notpad.]

Add required relative path to each of the project path and save in correct location:

> In my case to bring up one level 'BloombergPriceRequestService\'

**SO** project line(s) will look like this:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 11.00
# Visual Studio 2010
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "BloombergPaydownService", "BloombergPaydownService\BloombergPaydownService.csproj", "{17DDDD3E-CD39-48B4-BE3F-71E550FCBBFC}"
EndProject
Global
```

**Don't forget** to delete your old solution file!
[image: I have moved the solution file up one level]

Answer (score 3):

> if I cut the sln file and paste it in
>   the root folder,it doesn't load any of
>   my projects

Do this anyway, and try to open the solution. It will tell you that some projects couldn't be loaded: ignore the warning.

Then, go ahead and delete all the projects from the solution. After this right click the solution and select `Add => Existing project` and browse to your project file. Repeat for all projects in your solution.

Answer (score 3):

You need

1. to select solution in solution explorer
2. then to find button **File -> SaveAs solution.sln as**
3. Press it

---

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Editing the solution file is a hazardous way to do things and I found a better way. Just create a new solution and add copies of the folders containing the various projects (in their respective folders) to the project.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes, the solution file may contain **more than 5 projects** attached to it.

In that case, Creating the new solution and adding projects to that is cumbersome and takes more time.

You can just edit the solution file to load the projects correctly.

### Steps to do

sdas
1. Open the solution file in notepad or any text editor.
2. update the path which is underlined and made bold.

> Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "BloombergPaydownService", "***BloombergPaydownService\BloombergPaydownService.csproj***", "{17DDDD3E-CD39-48B4-BE3F-71E550FCBBFC}"

3. Save the file and open in Visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can do it:

1. Simply delete the entire project and create the entire project again in the other folder ( which is not recommended).
2. Here are the steps to follow without missing any files.

   a.       Goto Source control explorer Create a new folder or Just move the solution to which you want to move the folder to.

   b.      Load the solution in your local and it will prompt a message saying that do you want to reload it from source control click yes.

   c.       Once we load the solution you will see that the project you have moved won’t be loaded (Since we moved to the other folder)

   d.      So now, Remove the project which was not loaded and then add it as an existing project

   e.      I am sure that if you have added nugetPackages they won’t get loaded.

   f.        Goto file explorer of the particular project open the .csproj file and try to check the packages location, Error condition, Project reference and Import and apart from them if there are any 
   Which are pointing to a directory.

   g.       The simplest way is just adding some nuget package and see what is the path generated by visual studio.

   h.      Once we change the locations they will be loaded in references

   i.         After adding references try to build the solution and it will throw some build errors because we moved the project from one folder to other.

   j.        Add the project reference wherever needed after moving the files

   k.       Now the build will be succeeded.