# How to change the location of .sln file of a project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have 2 different projects in 1 solution but the .sln file is in one of these projects. I want the .sln file to be above them. You will understand better when you see images.

The ss of my solution explorer:

[image: a busy cat]

Here you can see there are 2 projects in 1 solution. Also the name of solution and one of my projects is the same  here.

Here is the place .sln file is located:

[image: a busy cat]

I want this .sln file to be located in here above them:

[image: a busy cat]

How do I do that? Thank you, have a nice day

Comment: Move the sln file to where you want it to be. Open the file in a text editor and change the paths to the projects inside it.

Comment: If you don't feel comfortable with editing the solution file you could simply create a new blank solution at the desired location and add the projects to it. If everything is to your liking you can delete the old solution .sln file

Comment: In VS2019(I guess in other version it also exists) there is a menu item File -> Save *.sln as, you can try it - place the new solution one level up.

Comment: With only 2 projects you could create a new .SLN and add both to it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [change solution file to a different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3377917/change-solution-file-to-a-different-folder)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have existing solution with projects I think the easiest way would be to select File -> Save *.sln as and select the location you need.

[image]

Visual studio will automatically update paths to projects.

I had something like this in the old solution

```
Project("{FAE04... "ConsoleApp7\ConsoleApp7.csproj", "{E0C7925E..."
```

The new one has

```
Project("{FAE04... "ConsoleApp7\ConsoleApp7\ConsoleApp7.csproj", "{E0C7925E..."
```

Checked for VS 2017 and 2019.

P.S. The solution should be selected in the Solution Explorer, else the "Save *sln as" item doesn't appear(it will suggest to save something else).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The sln file is relatively easy to edit in any text editor.

Close Visual Studio, move the solution to where you want it, then open the solution file in a text editor. Change the references to the proj files so that the relative path is included.

Here is an example from one of mine:

[image]

In this case, each of the proj files is in a subfolder and the sln file is in the root directory.